# Initial data not being fully displayed in django modelformset_factory

Tags: python, django, list-comprehension, defaultdict, formset

I am trying to display different initial data for each form in my formset. I don't get an error, however the data is not being totally displayed. Only the first object shows up. How do I fix this?

```
all_names = defaultdict(list)

for object in MyModel.objects.all():    #  obj1 = John, obj2 = Bob
    all_names['name'].append(object)

MyFormSet = modelformset_factory(MyModel, fields=('name'), extra=2)
formset = MyFormSet(initial=[{'name': n for n in names} for names in all_names.values()]
```

When I run:

```
[print(form.initial) for form in formset]
```

I get:

```
{'name': <Name: John>}
{}  # Where is my second object?
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I used a list and appended dictionaries to it instead of using defaultdict

```
all_names = list()  # used a list instead of defaultdict

for object in MyModel.objects.all():    #  obj1 = John, obj2 = Bob
    d = dict()
    d['name'] = object
    all_names.append(d)
```

and instead of:

```
formset = MyFormSet(initial=[{'name': n for n in names} for names in all_names.values()]
```

I did:

```
formset = MyFormSet(initial=all_names)
```